# Loop Cut and Slide Hotkeys

Tags: modeling

I'd like to change the centering of the loop cut (Factor 0) from a right click to a keyboard shortcut, say, 'Cmd Return'.

In 'User Preferences > Input > 3D View > Mesh > Loop Cut and Slide', I cannot see an option to change the input for the Edge Slide Factor.

Blender 2.78, OS X.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the Escape key does what you're talking about?

Comment: Thank you risingfall, I tried it and yes, the Escape key works. I was just wondering if there was a way to change it to a custom keyboard shortcut with some simple Python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I can give a more complete answer to describe how to make a custom shortcut.

The desired feature in this case appears to be under "Transform Modal Map" and the desired value is "Cancel".  It is by default mapped to "Any Esc" as shown below.  (This is in User Preferences-->Input.)

[image]

You can simply scroll down to the bottom of that section and click on "Add New" to create an alternative mapping for Cancel, as shown below where I have mapped it to "Ctrl-Alt-X":

[image]

. . . and you've now got a new keyboard shortuct for that function.  Obviously save your user preferences if you want it to persist.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Also, in order for the 'Cancel' shortcut to work with a Return key (I set it as 'Ctrl Return'), I had to change 'Confirm' from 'Any Return' to just 'Return'.